# Updating UIView makes a hash of subview's alignment / Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, core-graphics

I'm new in Swift. I want to make an app with a moving subview. I'm testing the app, and when i touch down the button, the subview moves with the correct value, but when the parent UIView updates because of changing label, the subview jump back to the origin coordinate what i set up in the storyboard. I use core graphics to draw circle. I want to move the circle on the screen by tap a button. How can i solved this problem?

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

          @IBOutlet weak var movingItem: MovingItem! /* inheritance from UIView */ 

          @IBAction func move() {

              self.movingItem.frame = CGRect(x: movingItem.frame.origin.x + 5.0, 
                                            y: movingItem.frame.origin.y, 
                                            width: movingItem.frame.width, 
                                            height: movingItem.frame.height)
         }

         override func viewDidLoad() {

              self.movingItem.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
              self.movingItem.setNeedsDisplay()
         }

//more code...

    }



@IBDesignable
class MovingItem: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextBeginPath(context)

        var rectForCircle = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectForCircle)

        UIColor.redColor().setFill()
        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
var rectForCircle = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectForCircle)
```

like this:

```
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, self.frame)
```

and insert line

```
self.movingItem.setNeedsDisplay()
```

after

```
self.movingItem.frame = CGRect(x: movingItem.frame.origin.x + 5.0, 
                                            y: movingItem.frame.origin.y, 
                                            width: movingItem.frame.width, 
                                            height: movingItem.frame.height)
```

Comment: the problem is the same. When the main UIView updates, the subview which containes the circle jump back. Between 2 updates, the subview moves correctly, but when uiview updates, the subview what is contained by the uiview jump back to the origin coordination. By-the-way,thank you!